# Lightning web component window.addEventListener local variables and HTML Dom is undefined

Tags: lightning-web-components

I am trying to access the local variable inside a method called from window.addEventListener callback but getting everything undefined.

```
renderedCallback() {
    this.captchaURL = captchaReURL;

    window.addEventListener("message", function (message) {
            if (message !== undefined && message.data === 'successGCP' && message.origin === window.location.origin) {

                this.captchaDone = true; // not able to access this.captchaDone getting undefined while this is declared.
                this.template.querySelector("lightning-button").disabled = false; // this.template is also undefined
            }
        }

    );
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is because **function(message)** declaration will have its own scope and ***this*** will refer to its own block in which you did not define ***captchaURL***. You can use Arrow function to solve this `(message) =>` - arrow function will take the scope of parent as it does not have its own scope.

```
window.addEventListener("message", (message) => {
        if (message !== undefined && message.data === 'successGCP' && message.origin === window.location.origin) {
            this.captchaDone = true; // not able to access this.captchaDone getting undefined while this is declared.
            this.template.querySelector("lightning-button").disabled = false; // this.template is also undefined
        }
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

We have implemented like below in one of my assignment. Try this once

```
@track data;

@api
getAddress() {
 return window.address;
}

@api
getValue() {
 return window.data;
}

connectedCallback() {
 if (window.addEventListener) {
  window.addEventListener("message", this.listenMessage, false);
 } else {
  window.attachEvent("onmessage", this.listenMessage);
 }
}
listenMessage(msg) {
 window.data = msg.data;
 this.data = msg.data;
 if (this.data !== 'Unlock') {
  window.address = msg.data
 }
}
```

Comment: Hi Dhanik, Thanks for your reply, actually, my issue is I am not able to access any local variable inside the callback method "listenMessage", even in your example you are not using any JS variables.
My requirement is, I want to enable a button inside the "listenMessage" method using  this.template.querySelector("lightning-button").disabled = false; but this.template is undefined, looks like LWC does not allow to access any page variables inside callback methods.

Comment: data is JS variable.

Comment: this.data must be undefined, so basically like said below it's not allowed access anything out of this scope.